# What is the proper OpenCV machine learning method to recognize music symbols?

Tags: c++, opencv

This is my current program which takes in a picture of a music score, remove the staff lines and split the music symbols into rectangles.
[image]
My question is: what is the proper and simple method to recognize these symbols ?
Some people suggested me using [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) but it's a bit too complicated for me to implement. I'm using OpenCV 3.0 (C++).

Comment: I feel HOG would be overkill for identifying objects with clearly-defined boundaries. As these are essentially glyphs, you should be able to repurpose Tesseract to recognise the symbols.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any OpenCV 3.0 supported method to do the same thing ?